# There exist $3$ positive numbers $x,y,z$ such that $x\cdot y\cdot z=100$ but $x^2+y^2+z^2<65$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have to show this using a form of calculus.
I know the answer is the cube root of $100$. I did this using intuition and upper and lower bounds but I have no idea how to show it from a calculus standpoint. Maybe showing the intersection of the surfaces?

Comment: Isn't this a typical Lagrange multipliers question?

Comment: @mathworker21 We actually skipped over that section. I'll go have a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: To prove that $x=y=z=\sqrt[3]{100}$ is the solution that gives the _minimum_ value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ can be done with calculus (or maybe without calculus; it's really just the AM-GM inequality, as shown in an answer already). But you can prove the statement you were asked to prove merely by exhibiting three numbers that satisfy it. Why should we use calculus to prove that $(\sqrt[3]{100})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{100})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{100})^2 < 65$?

Comment: Its a constraint my professor gave me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: by AM-GM $\,
x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 3 \sqrt[3]{x^2 y^2 z^2} = 30 \sqrt[3]{10} \simeq 64.63\,$, with equality iff $x=y=z\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Equivalent proof using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) for the concave function $\ln(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^+\,$:

$$
\ln \left(\frac{1}{3}x^2+\frac{1}{3}y^2+\frac{1}{3}z^2\right) \ge \frac{1}{3}\left(\ln(x^2)+\ln(y^2)+\ln(z^2)\right) = \ln(\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2})
$$

By monotonicity of $\ln(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ it follows that $\cfrac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2} = 10 \sqrt[3]{10}\,$, and because $\ln(x)$ is *strictly* concave the equality holds iff $x=y=z\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* #2 ] Yet another way to find the minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ using "*more*" calculus.

Starting from $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy\,$ with equality iff $x=y\,$, it follows that $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 2xy + z^2 = \cfrac{200}{z} + z^2\,$ with equality iff $x=y=\sqrt{\cfrac{100}{z}}\,$.

Let $f(z)=z^2+\cfrac{200}{z}\,$ then $f'(z)=2z - \cfrac{200}{z^2} = 0 \iff z^3 = 100\,$, so the minimum is attained for $z= \sqrt[3]{100}\,$, and $x = y = \sqrt{\cfrac{100}{\sqrt[3]{100}}}=\sqrt[3]{100}\,$.

Comment: This is probably the best way to go about this, but the question asker wants calculus in the solution.

Comment: @AlexLi One can prove AM-GM itself using Jensen's inequality for the concave function $y = \ln(x)\,$ (if it *has* to involve calculus).

Comment: I can show the answer algebraically and geometrically, but I use zero calculus in doing so. I suppose 3D graphing of functions is calculus in a sense.

Comment: @DaltonGillespie Are you familiar with convexity and Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @dxiv I'm familiar with convexity but not Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @DaltonGillespie The Jensen inequality is essentially the definition of convexity extrapolated to multiple intermediate points. FWIW I edited an alternative proof that uses it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x= 2\sqrt{5}$ , $y= 2\sqrt{5}$ $z=5 $.

Then of course $xyz=100$

And $x^2+y^2+z^2=20+20+25=65$.

Now set $x=y$ so $z= \frac{100}{x^2}$ therefore $x^2+y^2+z^2=2x^2+\frac{100}{x^4}$. Now define $$f(x)=2x^2+\frac{100}{x^4}$$
By differentiating we get $$f'(x)=\frac{4x^6-4\cdot100^2}{x^5}$$
so $x=100^{1/3}$ is the minimum of $f$.

However, we have found that $f(2\sqrt{5})=65$ so $f(100^{1/3})<65$

Answer (score 0):

Here’s crude but sound approach.

Consider spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$, especially for $r<\sqrt{65}$. You know that when $r=1$, the sphere has no intersection with the surface $xyz=100$, while certainly when $r$ is large, the intersection is nonempty.

Now, the set where the intersection is nonempty is closed, thus of form $[r_0,\infty\rangle$. Let’s find this $r_0$: it tells you when the surfaces $xyz=100$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=r_0^2$ are tangent. When this happens the gradients of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $xyz$ are parallel. For the former, the gradient is $(2x,2y,2z)$, and for the latter, $(yz,xz,xy)$. For these vectors to be parallel, we must have $(x,y,z)=\lambda(yz,xz,xy)$. That is, $\lambda=x/yz=y/xz=z/xy$. From $x/yz=y/xz$ we get $x^2=y^2$, so $x=y$, similarly $y=z$. So the tangency happens when $x=y=z$, at the point $(100^{1/3},100^{1/3},100^{1/3})$, where indeed $3\cdot100^{2/3}<65$.